# Flash browser game - HTTP + PHP vs Socket + Something else

Tags: php, flash, http, sockets

I am developing a non-real time browser RPG game (think [Kingdom of Loathing](http://www.kingdomofloathing.com/)) which would be played from within a Flash app. At first I just wanted to make the communication with server using simply URLLoader to tell PHP what I am doing, and using $_SESSION to store data needed in-between request.

I wonder if it wouldn't be better to base it on a socket connection, an app residing on a server written in Java or Python. The problem is I have never ever written such an app so I have no idea how much I'd have to "shift" my thoughts from simple responding do request (like PHP) to continuously working application. I won't hide I am also concerned about the memory and CPU usage of such Server app, when for example there would be hundreds of users connected. I've done some research.

I have tried to do some research, but thanks to my nil knowledge on the sockets subject I haven't found anything helpful. So, considering the fact I don't need real time data exchange, will it be wise to develop the server side part as socket server, not in plain ol' PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your game isn't something that's working in realtime you probably don't need to go down the socket route, though it's certainly a viable option. The nice thing about sockets is that updates would be instant without requiring page refresh (or server poll), so you're right to at least consider it.

If you do want to do a more real-time server setup, you might consider using something like Electroserver - this abstracts out much of the setup for you so you don't have to write your own server from scratch, plus it's free up to a certain number of concurrent users if I recall correctly.

Finally, a third option you have is a modified POST approach using AMF. Look into AMFPHP, it lets you call methods on a PHP back-end directly from your flash application. A little bit faster and easier than simply using POST stuff, but not quite as seamless as a socket connection or a specifically built gaming server.

Lots of options out there, it sounds like you are aware of this and kudos for trying to come up with the best approach rather than just rolling with what you know! I hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.

Here's a link to Electroserver - http://www.electro-server.com/

Comment: This Electroserver looks interesting, though far too pricey for me. I took a quick look through google and found BlazeDS and red5 (both free) but just a quick look at the installation instructions intimidated me greatly, I wish there was some easier to understand help on my case (Debian with Apache + PHP 5.3 + MySQL). I suppose I still have some time to investigate. Nevertheless, you nailed it perfectly - speed of response is what I want the most. Btw, I realize AMF is easier than simple POST, but do you have some source stating tests proving it is faster?

Comment: This tool is really neat, I just came across it while looking up an answer: http://www.jamesward.com/census/

Comment: Indeed, as odd as it might seem to me turns out to be faster! Thanks for help, it will surely come useful :).